# Huge picturebox (16000x16000)

Tags: vb.net, performance, picturebox

Sometimes, my users will use a 16000x16000 picturebox (which is located in a Panel, for autoscroll).

The picturebox is used like a tiles map. On it, I draw tiles for making maps (yes, it is a map editor)...

But the mere idea of being able to create a picturebox that huge, is terrible for performance.

I am told to "only load the visible area", but, what do they mean by "load" on a picturebox? Can I control that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to let the picturebox display complete images. Instead, you use the Paint event to draw the visible image portion yourself